# Huge speed difference between left join and inner join - Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join

It is known that left join is generally slower than inner join, but this difference seems out of proportion.
I have table A with 2,542,526 rows and table B with 30,444 rows. 
I ran this query, which returned values in just 37.6 seconds:

```
SELECT A.*, B.column_a 
INTO C FROM A, B
WHERE ST_Within(A.geom, B.geom) 
AND ST_DWithin(A.geom, B.geom, 0.000524)
```

Then, I ran this query (basically the same tables and columns but with left join. I wanted to get the extra info that a left join provides).

```
SELECT A.*, B.column_a 
INTO D FROM A 
LEFT JOIN B 
ON ST_Within(A.geom, B.geom) 
AND ST_DWithin(A.geom, B.geom, 0.000524)
```

That second query ran for 15 hours 30 minutes (hasn't finished yet, still running).

There are GIST indexes on both geom columns. Why is it taking so long? Am I missing something here? I knew it would take longer, but 15 hours seems out of proportion. I'm not very experienced with left joins, so my guess is that I am doing something wrong. I would like to know if I am making some kind of efficiency mistake or if this is normal.

Explain for first query:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..218269.24 rows=9 width=479)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on B  (cost=0.00..9799.44 rows=30444 width=4140)"
"  ->  Index Scan using latlonind on A (cost=0.41..6.84 rows=1 width=473)"
"        Index Cond: ((B.geom ~ geom) AND (geom && st_expand(B.geom, '0.000524'::double precision)))"
"        Filter: ((B.geom && st_expand(geom, '0.000524'::double precision)) AND _st_contains(B.geom, geom) AND _st_dwithin(geom, B.geom, '0.000524'::double precision))"
```

Explain for second query:

```
"Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.00..65359548445.44 rows=2542526 width=479)"
"  Join Filter: ((B.geom ~ A.geom) AND (A.geom && st_expand(B.geom, '0.000524'::double precision)) AND (B.geom && st_expand(A.geom, '0.000524'::double precision)) AND _st_contains(B.geom, A.geom) AND _st_dwithin(v (...)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on A (cost=0.00..281803.26 rows=2542526 width=473)"
"  ->  Seq Scan on B (cost=0.00..9799.44 rows=30444 width=4140)"
```

**EDIT**

Other important info (answering comments) is:

-Postgres version 9.5.15.

-`Select Count (*) from A` takes 250 msec.

-The first query returns 2,197,883 rows, which is almost the same number of results that the left join would return.

-When I do the `explain(analyze, buffers)` for both queries without the `into`, it doesn't end for the second one (I had it running for half an hour and didn't finish). The first one took 26 seconds (almost the same as executing the query), getting these results:

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=0.41..218269.24 rows=9 width=479) (actual time=0.111..26762.163 rows=2197883 loops=1)"
"  Buffers: shared hit=14121642 read=212529"
"  ->  Seq Scan on B  (cost=0.00..9799.44 rows=30444 width=4140) (actual time=0.004..29.747 rows=30444 loops=1)"
"        Buffers: shared hit=9 read=9486"
"  ->  Index Scan using geom on A  (cost=0.41..6.84 rows=1 width=473) (actual time=0.108..0.866 rows=72 loops=30444)"
"        Index Cond: ((B.geom ~ geom) AND (geom&& st_expand(B.geom, '0.000524'::double precision)))"
"        Filter: ((B.geom && st_expand(geom, '0.000524'::double precision)) AND _st_contains(B.geom, geom) AND _st_dwithin(geom, B.geom, '0.000524'::double precision))"
"        Rows Removed by Filter: 102"
"        Buffers: shared hit=14093482 read=196104"
"Planning time: 0.219 ms"
"Execution time: 26825.136 ms"
```

-I included a ST_DWithin() to see if it was a spatial analysis issue (which shouldn't be in the first place, since the inner join worked), having it and removing it doesn't change the output, it still won't finish.

**EDIT 2:**

After requested in the comments, I set `enable_seqscan = off` and the explain showed the following:

```
"Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=20000000000.00..79567050305.82 rows=25692511 width=461)"
"  Join Filter: ((B.geom ~ A.geom) AND _st_contains(B.geom, A.geom))"
"  ->  Seq Scan on A (cost=10000000000.00..10000157930.81 rows=2531781 width=455)"
"  ->  Materialize  (cost=10000000000.00..10000025348.66 rows=30444 width=4136)"
"        ->  Seq Scan on B  (cost=10000000000.00..10000009736.44 rows=30444 width=4136)"
```

Comment: Your second query does not limit the rows retrieved from table a, so it's not surprising that a query that returns over 2 million rows is slower than one that returns 9. And _writing_ those 2 million rows will also take some time. But 15 hours seems way too long for that nonetheless. It would be interesting to see the execution plan generated using `explain (analyze, buffers)` - at least for the select part (without writing the new table). How long does a `select count(*) from table_A` take?

Comment: What is your exact Postgres version (`select version();` will tell you)

Comment: What is the purpose of this combination of ST_Within and ST_DWithin?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Sorry, I forgot to add that info to the question. I will edit it.

Comment: The fact that Postgres _expects_ 9 rows but gets 2 million means that the statistics are wrong. Does running `analyze` on both tables change anything?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I just did `vacuum full a`, `vacuum full b`, `analyze a` and `analyze b`, but it still expects 9 rows for the first query.

Comment: What plan do you get if you `set enable_seqscan=off` before EXPLAINing the left join?

Comment: @jjanes I edited the question with your requested information. What do you have in mind?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name After the vacuum full and the analyze, I restarted postgres and now it gets the statistics right, but the left join still runs without ending.

Comment: Since it is still using the seq scan over B even with enable_seqscan off, then it is not a cost or estimation issue.  It thinks the index on B is simply not usable for this purpose.  I don't know why that is.  Are you sure there actually is a geometry index on B?

Comment: Yes, I had a gist index on B. I deleted the index, created it again, and now it works. My guess is that the index was corrupted or something. Now it ran in just 1.5 minutes. Thank you very much for your attention!